# servlet eclipse on tomcat7 HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, post

I'm new to servlet/jsp/portlet tecnology and i'm trying to understand,so as described i'm having an issue with this servlet :

---

```
package trekking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
    }

    /**
     * @param name 
     * @param pass 
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     * 
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String pass) throws ServletException, IOException {
String u,p;
        u=request.getParameter(name);
        p=request.getParameter(pass);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello World!</title>");
        out.println("You are "+u+"!");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

It is called in a html page by this form :

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
<label for="uname">UserName</label>
<input name="user" id="uname" type="text"></input>
<label for="pwd">Password</label>
<input name="pass" id="pwd" type="password"></input>
<input type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
```

I'm here if you need anything else.
Thank you. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't overriden the `doPost` method. You've overloaded it.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String pass) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

And since nothing is calling your overloaded method, you get the default inherited `HttpServlet#doPost()` behavior which returns a 405.

Comment: Great it works!(the IDE corrector has added those 2 parameters )

Comment: @user3254815 I think it added them because you were using `name` instead of a String literal `"name"`.

Comment: it's possible i will try this.

Comment: Yes it was so , now works perfectly, and i've understand how works passage of parameters! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'name' and 'pass' arguments from your doPost method.